# A use of <usual> and <always>

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request, word-difference

Please consider these examples:

> - The flower seller was **in his usual place**.
> - I’ll put the keys **in the usual place**.

In my sentences, we say **usual place**, meaning that something or someone is **usually (not always)** in; but what about the **permanent** situation. In other words, what shall I say when I want to say "the flower seller" or "the keys" are **always** there? What adjective do you normally use in that sense?

Comment: You could use "invariable" in this sense, but it is rather literary.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I know an adjective that could easily be substituted directly into the sentences you give. However here is how I would phrase such a sentence:

Since "usual" is an adjective, while "always" is an adverb you would have to add an additional verb for always to modify:

> The flower seller was where he always was
>
> I will put the keys where they always go

These sort of change the connotation by a lot. They make the text less neutral, and have more of an annoyed tone. At the very least they are more emotional then the original sentences.